# Vue warn: Computed property "projectName" was assigned to but it has no setter

Tags: javascript, vuex

I am trying to fill form with data with Vuex and after that edit it in the same form, but not working at the moment.

This is the code:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialogEditProject" max-width="1200px" height="200px">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="head-modal">
        <v-list-item-avatar class="logo-modal">
          <v-img src="@/assets/logo.svg"></v-img>
        </v-list-item-avatar>
        <span class="title-modal">EDIT PROJECT</span>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" onSubmit="return false;" lazy-validation>
        <v-row no-gutters>
          <v-col class="col1" cols="4">
            <span class="login-txt">Name Project</span>
            <v-row>
              <v-text-field
                v-model="projectName"
                @change="updateMessage"
                label
                :rules="nameProjectRules"
                solo
                name
                required
                shaped
              />
            </v-row>
            <span class="name-project">{{ projectName }}</span><br>
            <span class="login-txt">Author</span>
            <v-row>
              <v-text-field
                v-model="authorProject"
                label
                :rules="authorProjectRules"
                solo
                name
                required
                shaped
              />
            </v-row>

            <v-card-actions class="btn-new-project-modal">
              <v-btn id="btn-cancel-modal" class="btn-secondary" text @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
              <v-btn
                id="btn-create-modal"
                class="btn-primary"
                :disabled="!valid"
                type="submit"
                @click="updateProject"
                >Update</v-btn
              >
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-col>
      </v-form>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
 </template>
```

and JS:

```
    computed: {
    ...mapState('projects', ['projectName', 'authorProject', 'projectUuid']),
  },
```

Now in the text field appear the projectName, but when I try to do a PUT, not modify the field.
Any idea to fix that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a getter for `projectName` (that is from the `mapState` method), you do not have a setter for it, even though you have used it in `v-model` binding. A `v-model` binding is two-way, so it can both read/get and write/set.

You will need a corresponding `mapMutations` instead, so that changes made to `projectName` will commit a mutation or dispatch an action (both are considered setters) in your VueX store:

```
methods: {
    ...mapMutations('projects', ['projectName']),
}
```

...or:

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions('projects', ['projectName']),
}
```

Comment: I have included mapMutation right now, but I cannot refresh the projectName data when I modify the text field and click Submit in the form. Probably I need to include a Watch when I modify the text field or something like that?